# Asp.net Core 3.1- How can I return from Controller to Razor Page?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, razor-pages

I want when the user is logged in to the site, Go to the address I want in razor pages...

```
  if (rolename == "User")
       {            
        return RedirectToPage("Dashboard","Profile");
       }
```

This code did not work correctly ...

[image]

Here is the error message:

> InvalidOperationException: The relative page path 'Dashboard' can only be used while executing a Razor Page. Specify a root relative path with a leading '/' to generate a URL outside of a Razor Page. If you are using LinkGenerator then you must provide the current HttpContext to use relative pages.

how can do this?

Comment: Hi @AliKhansari,what's the error message?

Comment: Did you tried to LocalRedirect("/Dashboard/Profile")?

Comment: @Sasaman yes it's not work

Comment: @Rena `InvalidOperationException: The relative page path 'Dashboard' can only be used while executing a Razor Page. Specify a root relative path with a leading '/' to generate a URL outside of a Razor Page. If you are using LinkGenerator then you must provide the current HttpContext to use relative pages.`

Comment: @Sasaman you should put this into an answer ;)

Comment: Error says that you basically need to add leading '/'.

Comment: @Rena  your answer not work

Comment: @AliKhansari Can you show us your project structure? Pages and Controllers, your Startup class...

Comment: Hi @AliKhansari,where is your Dashboard.cshtml located?And are your configure razor pages routing in your Startup.cs?Please share with us.Do not just say do not work.

Comment: @Rena I Edited My question and added image

Comment: Hi @AliKhansari, So you want to call Dashboard.cshtml OnGet method?If so,check my updated answer.

Comment: @Rena thanks I edit your answer ,its worked

Comment: You're welcome! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RedirectToPage have multiple methods with different parameter,what you did relate to the following method:

```
        //
    // Summary:
    //     Redirects (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.StatusCodes.Status302Found) to the specified
    //     pageName using the specified pageHandler.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   pageName:
    //     The name of the page.
    //
    //   pageHandler:
    //     The page handler to redirect to.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     The Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RedirectToPageResult.
    [NonAction]
    public virtual RedirectToPageResult RedirectToPage(string pageName, string pageHandler);
```

In your case,it should be:

```
return RedirectToPage("/Profile/Dashboard");
```

Also,be sure add razor pages routing:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {
     services.AddRazorPages(); 
 }

 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
 {
        //...

     app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
     {               
         endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Privacy}/{phrase?}");

         endpoints.MapRazorPages();

     });          
 }
```